# como achar e alterar uma linha especifica python?

Tags: python

eu to aprendendo Python e andei criando arquivos txt, adicionando coisas e rescrevendo eles mas n consegui modificar uma linha especifica, como posso fazer isso?? e também eu queria saber como descobrir em que linha uma string especifica esta, eu já consigo pesquisar mas n consegui fazer o programa descobrir a linha onde a string esta :|

para pesquisar eu enstou usando...

```
palavra = input('palavra a pesquisar ')
for line in open('perfil.txt'):
    if palavra in line:
        print(line)
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Existe alguma forma de sobrescrever uma linha específica de um arquivo de texto usando Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257293/existe-alguma-forma-de-sobrescrever-uma-linha-espec%c3%adfica-de-um-arquivo-de-texto)

Answer (score 3):

Para substituir determinada linha de um arquivo, você pode usar essa função:

```
def alterar_linha(path,index_linha,nova_linha):
    with open(path,'r') as f:
        texto=f.readlines()
    with open(path,'w') as f:
        for i in texto:
            if texto.index(i)==index_linha:
                f.write(nova_linha+'\n')
            else:
                f.write(i)
```

Onde: path é uma string com o nome do arquivo que você quer alterar; index_linha é o número da linha contado a partir de 0; nova_linha é uma string do conteúdo da nova linha.

Para achar em qual linha está uma string, você pode usar essa função:

```
def encontrar_string(path,string):
    with open(path,'r') as f:
        texto=f.readlines()
    for i in texto:
        if string in i:
            print(texto.index(i))
            return
    print('String não encontrada')
```

Onde string é a string que você quer encontrar. Qualquer dúvida, comenta aí.

Comment: Benedito, só um pequeno reparo, `texto.index(i)` falha se houverem linhas iguais, a função vai só buscar a primeira ocorrência, podes fazer: `for line_num, i in enumerate(texto): ... print(line_num)`

Comment: Ou apenas substituir o conteúdo na lista `texto`, gerada por `readlines()` na posição desejada (mais 1, visto que a numeração das linhas em um arquivo inicia em 1, ao tempo que os índices da lista iniciam em 0).

Answer (score 1):

```
path = 'C:\\seu_Diretorio\\'                       # Caminho do diretorio
files = [
            f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))
        ]                                          # Varrendo cada arquivo
filesLen = len(files)                              # Pegando o numero de arquivos do diretorio
dataAtual = datetime.datetime.now()
one_days_ago = dataAtual - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
y = 1
for x in range(filesLen):                          # Repetindo o loop de acordo com a quantidade de arquivos
    print(f'=====INICIO DA LEITURA DO ARQUIVO {files[x]} ============')
    f = open(f'{path}{files[x]}', 'r')             # Abrindo o arquivo
    linhas = f.readlines()                         # Pegando cada linha do arquivo.txt e jogando dentro de um array
    z = linhas[0].replace(
        linhas[0][15:23], dataAtual.strftime('%d%m%Y')
    )                                              ## Substituindo a primeira linha
    with open(f'{path}{files[x]}', 'w') as f:      # Abrindo o arquivo para poder escrever/modificar a linha
        for i, line in enumerate(linhas, 1):       # O 'i' é o indice da linha o line é a linha
            if i == 1:                             # Se o indice da linha for igual a 1 ele ira executar esse bloco
                f.writelines(z)
                print('A linha escolhida foi modificada')
            else:                                  # Senao ira executar este
                f.writelines(line)
```

**Tem algumas coisas desnecessárias no codigo com por exemplo as variáveis:
dataAtual, one_days_ago, z(essa variavel foi usada para fazer o replace na linha em que eu escolhi, altere ela para a linha que voce quer e caso queria escolher o indice da letra que queira ser alterada), com esse codigo consegui alterar a primeira linha do meu arquivo e tbm a palavra no meio da string, espero que possa ser util para voce tbm
**