# Existe alguma forma de sobrescrever uma linha específica de um arquivo de texto usando Python?

Tags: python

Eu gostaria de editar uma linha específica de um arquivo, mas o **file.write()** não permite esse tipo de manipulação.

Sendo o Texto:

```
1 "Ola"
2 "Como vai?"
3 "Tudo bem?"
```

Eu gostaria de Editar apenas a linha 2:

```
1 "Ola"
2 "Boa tarde"
3 "Tudo bem?"
```

Em python podemos ler uma linha específica usando o **file.readline()**, mas não encontrei uma função que permitisse editar uma linha específica. 
Existe uma função para isso?

Comment: Tem como por um exemplo do texto original e do desejado?

Comment: essa pergunta está bem clara para mim.

Comment: Agora eu entendi a pergunta perfeitamente

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A forma mais fácil de você fazer isso, ao meu ver, é criar um *buffer*
temporário para armazenar o conteúdo do arquivo final, substituindo a linha que
você deseja alterar. A lógica é simples: abrir o arquivo em modo leitura,
percorrer suas linhas e, se a linha for a desejada, escrever no *buffer* o novo
conteúdo, caso contrário, escrever o próprio conteúdo da linha. Ao final,
substituir o conteúdo do arquivo pelo conteúdo do *buffer*.

```
from io import StringIO

buffer = StringIO()

with open('data.txt', 'r') as stream:
    for index, line in enumerate(stream):
        # index == 1 representa a segunda linha do arquivo:
        buffer.write('Novo conteúdo da linha\n' if index == 1 else line)

with open('data.txt', 'w') as stream:
    stream.write(buffer.getvalue())
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/ComposedWearyStoat)</sup>

Porém, desta forma, o conteúdo acaba ficando armazenado todo em memória através
do *buffer*, o que pode afetar o desempenho da aplicação conforme o tamanho do
arquivo em questão.

Comment: Obrigado... Isso deve ajudar.

Comment: Eu precisei editar uma pequena parte para que pudesse funcionar no python 2.x: 
`from io import BytesIO as StringIO`

Comment: @EvinerRayzeckSantos No Python 2 você pode fazer `from cStringIO import StringIO`

Comment: vlw... Também funcionou

Comment: A implementação do **try:** não é conveniente pois o erro recebido não era **ImportError**. Sendo assim, o script passa por essa parte sem erro até encontrar o erro que eu tinha recebido: **TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'**

Comment: @EvinerRayzeckSantos mas esse erro foi dado em que linha do código? Acho que aí o erro seria na string, possivelmente no `buffer.write`, onde seria necessário colocar `u'Novo conteúdo...'`, com o prefixo `u`.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):`
`  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>`
 ` File "teste.py", line 17, in <module>`
`    buffer.write('O teste tambem funcionou\n' if index == 1 else line)`
`TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'`

Comment: Mas esse ocorreu mesmo sem o `try` para importar a classe, não?

Comment: Como eu disse, o erro não é ImportError, isto é, o interpretador não me impede de usar a linha **from io import StringIO**

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/257719/112052), que no final comentou o seguinte:

> *Porém, desta forma, o conteúdo acaba ficando armazenado todo em memória através do buffer, o que pode afetar o desempenho da aplicação conforme o tamanho do arquivo em questão.*

De fato, isso pode ser um problema. Mas não é só isso: ao escrever no mesmo arquivo com a opção `w`, o arquivo é truncado e o seu conteúdo se perde. E se ocorrer algum erro durante a escrita, o arquivo ficará corrompido.

Uma solução seria primeiro escrever o novo conteúdo em um arquivo temporário, e só no final, se tudo deu certo, renomear este arquivo temporário para o original:

```
import shutil, tempfile

# lê do arquivo e escreve em outro arquivo temporário
with open('data.txt', 'r') as arquivo, \
     tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False) as out:
    for index, linha in enumerate(arquivo, start=1):
        if index == 2: # linha 2, mudar o conteúdo
            out.write('Novo conteúdo\n')
        else: # não é linha 2, escreve a linha sem modificação
            out.write(linha)

# move o arquivo temporário para o original
shutil.move(out.name, 'data.txt')
```

Assim, se ocorrer algum problema durante a escrita, somente o arquivo temporário ficará corrompido (mas como é temporário, não é tão problemático assim), e o original ficará intacto.

Para obter o número da linha, usei [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), mas como o *default* é começar a contagem em zero, adicionei o parâmetro `start` para que comece em 1 (assim a segunda linha estará no índice 2 em vez do 1).