# Python CSV Como reescrever apenas uma linha do arquivo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Eu tenho uma linha que guarda dentro do arquivo as seguintes colunas:

```
ID   Nome    Telefone   Descrição DataEntrada  HoraEntrada
```

O ID é basicamente o número da linha e é através dele que eu vou procurar saber qual linha reescrever.
Eu sei que provavelmente pra reescrever isto eu tenho que ler e escrever o arquivo inteiro, porém, não sei como faço pra adicionar outros valores a essa linha.

Resultado desejado:

```
ID   Nome    Telefone   Descrição    DataEntrada    HoraEntrada    DataSaída HoraSaída    Valor
```

Comment: Tem colunas a mais no resultado esperado, então você vai querer adicionar valores em **todas as linhas**? Para editar apenas uma linha do arquivo, você pode ler sobre [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/257293/5878).

Comment: Quando fiz o programa, fiz para entrada de produtos e pra ter um controle, agora quando fui melhorar o programa, quero fazer com que mostre o dia e hora que o produto saiu e o valor que foi pago por ele.

Comment: Eu quero, por exemplo, sempre que a linha tiver um componente [8], ele me exiba o valor que foi pago por isso

Comment: A sugestão "de verdade" é que você usar o SQLite e deixe isso numbanco e dados em vez de manter seus dados num arquivo texto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como escrevi no comentário -  se você tem um arquivo texto com dados, e vai querer ficar alterando esses dados, provavelemtne você está usando a solução errada.

Usar um banco de dados "autocontido" no formato do SQLite em Python é trivial: não requer nenhuma instalação e seus dados ficam todos contidos num único arquivo que você pode anexar em e-mails, copiar pra pendrives,  do mesmo jeito.

Dito isso, como você bem colocou na pergunta, a única forma de se alterar dados num arquivo texto que não tenha campos de largura fixa é reescrever o arquivo todo.  A prática é recomendada *mesmo* para arquivos com campos de largura fixa: além da complicação lógica de se escrever na posição e comprimento exato dos dados, os sistemas operacionais modernos em hardware atual só escrevem no disco múltiplos de 4096 bytes (pode ser até 512 em hardware embarcado) - ou seja não há qualquer ganho de performance a não ser que o arquivo tenha múltiplos megabytes.

Bom, você não deu nenhum exemplo do seu programa nem como estão seus dados. Mas o primeiro passo, já que você vai re-escrever o arquivo inteiro é ... ler o arquivo inteiro. Daí você faz alterações na memória, dos dados que quer mudar. E aí você...grava o arquivo inteiro.

O CSV do Python tem como ler cada linha do CSV para um dicionário, em que o cabeçalho das colunas é a chave, e o valor, cada coluna.

Para mudar o arquivo, você process cada dicionário e ponha a data e hora.
O ideal é ter as datas e horas como objetos `datetime.datetime` no Python, e escreve-los no arquivo de texto com o método `.isoformat`. Mas para ler de volta essas datas, você teria que usar o método `datetime.strptime` que é para datas genéricas. Então se quiser usar o `strftime` para colocar as datas num formato mais conveniente, tudo bem.

Agora, se você estiver usando um banco de dados, e declarar a coluna como `datetime`, o Python faz tudo isso pra você.

Eu não vou por código nesta respsota.
Eu poderia ficar mais 10 minutos aqui e colocar um exemplo de como ler um CSV como dicionários, atualiza-los e escreve-los de volta, mas duas coisas: é um formato muito ruim pra você manter os dados, e dois: não tem nenhum código seu para dar dicas ou apontar como integrar isso. Se tivesse aí já como você faz para ler o seu arquivo no uso normal do seu programa, essa seria só uma funcionalidade a mais, mas não é o caso.

A sugestão de qualquer forma é: tire umas duas horas para aprender sobre sqlite - faça um tutorial interativo, com calma. Depois volte a pensar nesse programa.

Comment: Eu gostaria de poder mandar o código, mas ta muito grande!!
Mas basicamente ele escreve cada linha desse jeito ai. Eu sei que tem programas que facilitam a vida com banco de dados, mas estou fazendo isso do meu jeito justamente para exercitar a prática do python, já que sou novato. Se quiser dar uma olhada, eu posso te mandar o arquivo pra você rodar ai.

Comment: então - aproveita que é prática, e pratique o sqlite - possivelmetne você consegue atualizar seu programa inteiro em menos d eum dia, e então vai ter uma "aplicação de verdade". Tem um e-mail no meu perfil daqui.