# Como eu posso substituir uma linha de um arquivo no python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = open('arquivo.txt', 'r+')
x.readlines()
```

'''
Vai aparecer esse arquivo em linhas separadas
'''

['1\n','2\n','3\n']

'''
Eu queria poder trocar o 2 por um 4
'''

Comment: Tente nos explicar melhor o que você está tentando fazer, pela sua pergunta um simples `replace`  já funcionaria.

Comment: Seria isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/257293/112052 ? Ver também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/461358/112052

Answer (score -3):

Não sei se entendi bem, mas acho que é isso que está tentando fazer.

```
x = [open('arquivo.txt', 'r+').readlines()]
file = open('arquivo.txt', 'w')


def imprimir_valor():
    for i, valor in enumerate(x[0]):
        print(valor)
    print(20*'----', '\n')


def novo_valor(lista, item, n_valor):
    x[lista][item] = n_valor


imprimir_valor()
novo_valor(0, 1, '4\n')
imprimir_valor()
file.write(str(x[0]))
```

Comment: Neste caso carreguei o arquivo em uma lista, aí fica fácil manipular os valores através dos índices. No final a lista é convertida para uma string e salva em um arquivo que substitui o arquivo original.

Answer (score -3):

Uma forma de manter a formatação no novo arquivo gerado é utilizando a função `join`

```
x = [open('arquivo.txt', 'r+').readlines()]
file = open('arquivo.txt', 'w')


def novo_valor(lista, item, n_valor):
    x[lista][item] = n_valor


novo_valor(0, 1, '4\n')
file.write(str("").join(x[0]))
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).